# Запросы JSON VK_BOT_API

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api, requests

Пишу бота на python для VK и у меня проблема с реализацией запросов через requests.

```
import requests 
url = 'http://111.111.111/script?type=online&access_token=test' # (допустим это тот самый адрес)
online = requests.get(url)
```

Запрос идёт к игровому серверу (MTA - GTA San Andreas)

Как расшифровать ответ и внедрить его в ответ бота?
Проще говоря, я кинул боту команду: `/online` - он должен отправить онлайн на сервере в текущий момент.

```
if msg == "/online":
  sender(user_id, "ответ от сервера")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так покажите, что запрос возвращает